# Convert a string with bytes to a float array

Tags: python, numpy

I get a string from a socket that contains a float array as bytes. Now I want to convert this string in to a float (4bit) numpy array.

for example I get:

```
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

and I want an output like this:

```
[0, 0]
```

Comment: Your output is a *list*. Also, are you on Python 2 or 3? Also, do you mean *32bit* float? Pretty sure you don't mean 4 bit...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fromstring` method and specify the number of bytes to convert to (`32 bits = 4 bytes` in this particular case):

```
np.fromstring( "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", np.float32 )
```

You need to ensure your `string` has lenght multiple of `4`. Otherwise `numpy` will rise:

```
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

Comment: Using `fromstring` in this way is deprecated as of 1.14, since it silently does bad things on `unicode` objects - use [`np.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) instead, which only allows `bytes` objects.